# Searching for Plural Terms in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anyone know how to make the Wordpress system adapt to plural searches?

IE, if a user searches for "Responsive Themes", it will also search for "Responsive Theme"

Answer (score 0):

[Here’s a good answer](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-plural-singular-search-terms). It recommends using the `inflector` class in `wp-dev-library` to create a custom function that will singularize plural words to do just what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a wordpress expert but I can recommend a simple shortcut that covers words whose plurals end in "s".

Take the incoming search term(s), and strip the final "s" from any word.

I suppose wordpress provides you the search query as an array of terms? If not, you can create one like this:

```
$query_string = 'Dogs and cats';

$search_terms = array_filter(explode(' ',$query_string)); // explode creates an array, filter removes any empty elements.

$search_terms_singular = array_map('rtrim',$search_terms,array_fill(0,sizeof($search_terms),'s')); // trim "s" from the end of every word.
```

Now search your db using the singular terms. Plural terms should also match if you are using SQL `LIKE "%term%"` or `LIKE "term%"`, (and I think for `FULLTEXT` also).

If you need to make the singular search back into a string:

```
$singular_query_string = implode(' ',$search_terms_singular);
```

Again, this is a quick and dirty solution that only affects words ending in "s", but I have used similar code in Magento and found it to be quite effective.